# Preg replace divs with li but keep class active

Tags: php, html, pagination, preg-replace

Trying to get my head around how to create a PHP preg replace for a string that will convert

```
<div class="active make_link">1</div>
<div class="make_link digit"><a href="">2</a></div>
<div class="make_link digit"><a href="">3</a></div>
etc
```

to

```
<li class="active">1</li>
<li><a href="">2</a></li>
<li><a href="">3</a></li>
etc
```

Figured out how to replace the elements but not how to keep the class active.

```
$new_pagination = preg_replace('/<div[^>]*>(.*)<\/div>/U', '<li>$1</li>', $old_pagination);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..You can do this using `str_ireplace` too

```
<?php
$html='<div class="active make_link">1</div>
<div class="make_link digit"><a href="">2</a></div>
<div class="make_link digit"><a href="">3</a></div>';

echo str_ireplace(array('<div','</div','class="active make_link"','class="make_link digit"'),array('<li','</li','active',''),$html);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may seem a bit excessive, but it's a good use-case for XSLT:

```
$xslt = <<<XML
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="div">
    <li>
      <xsl:if test="@*[name()='class' and contains(., 'active')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
XML;
```

It uses the identity rule and then overrides handling for `<div>`, adding a `class="active"` for nodes that have such a class name.

```
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xslt);

$xsl->importStyleSheet($doc);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="active make_link">1</div>
<div class="make_link digit"><a href="">2</a><div>test</div></div>
<div class="make_link digit"><a href="">3</a></div>
HTML;

$doc->loadHTML($html);

echo $xsl->transformToDoc($doc)->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This idea needs some work, it throws away attributes and mangles the child nodes.

Comment: @pguardiario OP only wanted to keep active class; not sure what you mean with mangling of child nodes, though ... did you mean nested `<div>`?

Comment: Right, it's fine as long as there's no other attributes or more than 1 child node. Not the best solution though obviously.

Comment: @pguardiario XSLT to the rescue :)

Comment: Well I give it an A for effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Or simple html dom:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$doc = str_get_html($string);
foreach($doc->find('div') as $div){
  $div->tag = 'li';
  preg_match('/active/', $div->class, $m);
  $div->class = @$m[0];
}

echo $doc;
```